# Is it possible to debug in source-level under LLVM-vs2014?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, clang, llvm

I installed the latest llvm on Windows with Visual Studio 2015.

I created a C++ project and choose **LLVM-vs2014** as the platform toolset in VS 2015.

I can compile and the compiler output as follows:

> ------ Rebuild All started: Project: Cxx1zTest, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
>   1>  Cxx1zTest.vcxproj -> D:\projects\Cxx1zTest\x64\Debug\Cxx1zTest.exe
>   1>  Cxx1zTest.vcxproj -> D:\projects\Cxx1zTest\x64\Debug\Cxx1zTest.pdb (Full PDB)
>   ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I can also run the project successfully.

**The issue is:**

I cannot debug the project in source-level as **VC++** does; though the full pdb is generated.

After I press F5 to start debug, the debug window outputs:

> 'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'D:\projects\QbgTestServer\x64\Debug\Cxx1zTest.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. 'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB
>   file. 'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   'Cxx1zTest.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. The thread 0x16ec has exited with
>   code 0 (0x0). The thread 0x115dc has exited with code 0 (0x0). The
>   thread 0x9740 has exited with code 0 (0x0). The program '[1108]
>   Cxx1zTest.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

What's the root cause?

Is there a workaround to fix the issue?

Comment: Why you can't ?

Comment: Might be some path issue: `D:\projects\Cxx1zTest\x64\Debug\Cxx1zTest.pdb` vs. `D:\projects\QbgTestServer\x64\Debug\Cxx1zTest.exe`. Make sure you have the symbol directories set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the warning messages in the output windows, they are all the system DLLs which we don't have debug symbols for.

Open your VS IDE:

Go to Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols, please select the checkbox "Microsoft Symbol Servers", and then Visual Studio would download PDB files automatically.